# Cleanup/Optimize multiple variable script - download different packages

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm recently jumping back into learning new skills.  Some of which is dipping my toes into scripting.

To start, I want to pull the latest versions of multiple packages, in one script.  I do this by pulling the version number into a variable, and then feeding that variable into the download URL.

So the below "works" (some of y'all might recognize the packages, and know what I'm playing with)...but I know it's not "optimal", and I'm not content with just getting something working and then moving on, when I know I could probably do better.

I don't think I'm truly grasping how the various 'while' options work, as I need the "break" in there in order to stop the loop.  I initially considered nesting 'for' loops...but that seemed even uglier to me.

Or maybe I'm simply using the wrong tool for my task...

```
while true; do
    crictlver=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/releases/latest" | jq -r .tag_name)
    runcver=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/opencontainers/runc/releases/latest" | jq -r .tag_name)
    cniver=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/containernetworking/plugins/releases/latest" | jq -r .tag_name)
    containerdver=$(curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/containerd/containerd/releases/latest" | jq -r .tag_name)
    containerdvernum=$( curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/containerd/containerd/releases/latest" | jq -r .tag_name | sed 's/^v//')
    k8sver=$(curl -s "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt")
        wget --timestamping \
        https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/releases/download/${crictlver}/crictl-${crictlver}-linux-amd64.tar.gz \
        https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/releases/download/${runcver}/runc.amd64 \
        https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/releases/download/${cniver}/cni-plugins-linux-amd64-${cniver}.tgz \
        https://github.com/containerd/containerd/releases/download/${containerdver}/containerd-${containerdvernum}.linux-amd64.tar.gz \
        https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/${k8sver}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl \
        https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/${k8sver}/bin/linux/amd64/kube-proxy \
        https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/${k8sver}/bin/linux/amd64/kubelet;
    break
    done
```

Any thoughts, suggestions, or feedback about how to compact this is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Your while statement does nothing, since you break ir in the first loop. And as it is infinite, you need a condition to break it. What is the thing you want to repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Well, that's the thing...  I don't really want to repeat anything.  I just want to download the latest versions once.
I started off thinking I'd use "for", but I wanted to define multiple variables (the crictlver, runcver, etc).  In my sniffing around I saw many folks suggesting to use "while" when someone wanted to have multiple variables.  But that was in the context of "while read".
So I tried it...and it technically works...but I don't feel it's "correct".